# Reducing lme4 mixed model to fixed effects regression eqution

Tags: r, predict, lme4

I don't see a definitive answer to this question on any related threads so I wonder if you can give me one

I’m aware that the predict function can be used to generate predictions fo new cases “at the population level”, i.e. without specifying information on random variables

I would like to do prediction outside R on a web interface to which users submit their scores for the fixed effect variables I’ve used in my mixed model, but do not submit any information with respect to what level of various random variables they lie on. My question is whether use of the predict function level in this way simply gives you the output you would get from something that looks like a standard regression equation

Thus given a mixed model

```
Fit<-lmer(y ~ Fix1 + Fix2 + Fix3 + (1+ Fix1 + Fix2 + Fix3 | Rand1 ) + (1|Rand2), data = df, REML = FALSE)
```

Can one predict at the population level with

```
Y = intercept + Beta1.Fix1 + Beta2.Fix2 + Beta3.Fix3
```

I’ve been advised that this is so but I find that when I use this regression equation to create predicted scores for the actual data that produced the model, these are lower on average than the observed scores (so the residuals don’t sum to zero). In contrast, if I do the same check with a regression equation given by a linear, not mixed model they do.

Many thanks for any thoughts, 
Tom

Comment: This sounds like you are asking a statistics question - e.g., how to make population-level predictions from a mixed model - instead of a programming question - how to make population-level predictions on a merMod object in R. [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) may be a better place for this.

Comment: My  apologies, I've posted there instead